# Updating data using JQuery and Flask

Tags: ajax, flask, sqlalchemy

I have been trying to update database without refreshing page. I got solution of using AJAX however, there is some issue and not able to work it out. Would you mind to have a look and suggest change.

I have added `<script>` for file path of `.js` file already. However, not able to update data in mysql. I am able to get data in html but not able to update.

app.py

```
@app.route('/update', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def update():
    # all_data = BankData.query.all()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        start_date = request.form.get('start_date')
        end_date = request.form.get('end_date')

        searched_data = db.session.query(BankData).filter(
            BankData.process_date.between(start_date, end_date))

    # db.session.add(searched_data)
    # db.session.commit()
    # start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date,
    return render_template('update.html', start_date=start_date, end_date=end_date, searched_data=searched_data)


@app.route('/update_two', methods=['POST'])
def update_two():

    # searched_data = session.get('searched_data')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        new_data = BankData.query.get(request.form['id'])
        for data in new_data:
            print(data.id)

        new_data.id = request.form['id']
        new_data.process_date = request.form['date']
        new_data.description = request.form['description']
        new_data.debit = request.form['debit']
        new_data.category = request.form['category']
        db.session.commit()
        print("data submitted")

        return jsonify({'result': 'success'})
```

app.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('.updateButton').on('click', function () {

        var data_id = $(this).attr('data.id');

        var date = $('#dateInput' + data.id).val();
        var description = $('#descriptionInput' + data.id).val();
        var debit = $('#debitInput' + data.id).val();
        var category = $('#categoryInput' + data.id).val();



        req = $.ajax({
            url: '/update_two',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { date: date, description: description, debit: debit, category: category, id: data_id }
        });

        req.done(function (data) {

            $('#dataSection' + data_id).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);
            // $('#dataNumber' + data_id).text(data.search_data);

        });


    });

});
```

Comment: When you say there is an issue what does that mean exactly? what is the error you encounter?

Comment: No error but I can not see POST message to update_two route so looks like .js file and update.html not connecting and there is no call to flask route

Comment: So basically data is not being updated however I can see all data in .html but when I click button on click event of button in .js is not happening

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is corrected code. and it is working fine.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.updateButtonInvoice').on('click', function () {

        var data_id = $(this).attr('data_id');

        var invoiceNumber = $('#invoiceNumberInput' + data_id).val();
        var invoiceDate = $('#invoiceDateInput' + data_id).val();
        var weekEndDate = $('#weekEndDateInput' + data_id).val();
        var storeNumber = $('#storeNumberInput' + data_id).val();
        var description = $('#descriptionInput' + data_id).val();
        var totalExGst = $('#totalExGstInput' + data_id).val();
        var category = $('#categoryInput' + data_id).val();



        req = $.ajax({
            url: '/updatetwoInvoice',
            type: 'POST',
            data: { invoiceNumber: invoiceNumber, invoiceDate: invoiceDate, weekEndDate: weekEndDate, storeNumber: storeNumber, description: description, totalExGst: totalExGst, category: category, id: data_id }
        });

        req.done(function (data) {

            $('#dataSectiontwoInvoice' + data_id).fadeOut(1000).fadeIn(1000);

        });


    });




});
```

Comment: Hi, I am having a similar issue. I retrieving the data from ajax but its not updating on jinja

Comment: So there are no changes you made on the view function of the initial problem you posted? What about the html template?